# AWS ElasticSearch: How to find the associated security group

Tags: aws-security-group, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to find the security group of my Elasticsearch domain in AWS but from the Elasticsearch console, I can't find it. My ES domain is not inside a VPC but is exposed to the Web with some authentication.

What I want to do is to whitelist some IP addresses and block the rest and I wanted to implement it using the security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no security group but an access policy where you can whitelist IP addresses or ARNs. This can be done from the ElasticSearch console. [image]